# Why does lua string.find returns wrong number

Tags: lua

```
local num = string.find("i want this to work --", "--")
return num
```

So this piece of code should return 21 but its actually returning 1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-` is a special character in Lua patterns. To do a literal match, your second argument to `string.find` needs to be `'%-%-'`.

Alternatively, if you don't want to deal with pattern semantics, you can pass a 4th argument of `true` to tell `string.find` to take the second argument as a literal string instead of as a pattern:

```
string.find("i want this to work --", "--", 1, true)
```

Comment: Or you can use the final arg for `string.find` which sets wither or not to take the pattern as plain text:  `string.find("some--thing", "--", 1, true)`

Comment: @Nifim: I didn't think of that. I'm adding that to my answer.